# Is it possible to provide color management for css colors in Chrome

Tags: css, colors, three.js, color-management

I am working on a project where we have designers that work in Adobe RGB and are used to seeing the more vibrant colors from that spectrum in Illustrator. However we have been building an application that will allow them to do their work in a web browser using a THREE JS 3D workspace.

Because we have been creating the color swatches using CSS background color and applying RGBA to the meshes in THREE we have been displaying everything in sRGB, and now the designers are complaining the colors don't seem right in the browser.

I know that current versions of Chrome support color management for images but I can't find any information about CSS or Three JS. Does anyone know if it's even possible to control the color profiles for these areas, or are we just going to have to live with sRGB?

Answer (score 0):

We have the very same problem, i found no way to control the CSS Colors. I think this will maybe change with the mediaQuery keyword, but I did also not found out if it will affect CSS colors.
http://furbo.org/color/ResponsiveColor/

We only need a special set of colors so now we store them in a texture and make a lookup, but I guess this is no solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible now, but it will be possible in the future when draft specification from W3C will come into browsers... (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/)

It is now already possible in latest Safari of MacOS BigSur. There is even a special test here.

Console in Safari also has Color managed color picker.

Comment: Test is here https://codepen.io/NV/pen/XLOOdE

Answer (score 0):

Is your destination the web? Then Adobe RGB is not presently supported, and is not recommended.

#### The Standard for the Web is sRGB

The W3 *defined* the standard for web content as sRGB. In the future, CSS4 will support other colorspaces. Right now? Stick with sRGB.

Chrome, and most browsers do not support *any* color management for CSS. Safari is the only one I know that does, at least without tweaking some internal experimental options on the others.

When possible, I suggest working in the destination space (though possibly working at a higher bit depth)  then there will not be these kinds of "surprises". In the interim, you might try *converting* the existing work from AdobeRGB to sRGB using "perceptual intent" or "relative colorimetric".

Also, you can find the docs for CSS here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-roadmap/

Comment: In M94 Chrome already activated ICC WCG in HDR using scRGB. So... Safari supports "color: color(display-p3 1.0 0 0 0)" and soon Chrome will support it too.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников That is not release it is beta, requiring activation past the "WARNING: EXPERIMENTAL FEATURES AHEAD! " warning. Nevertheless that is not the point actually. I am talking about color management for CSS colors, NOT TAGGED IMAGES. MacOS does an okay job of color management, but there are a lot of other OSes and devices out there that don't. And at present the **standard** for the web is **defined as sRGB**. CSS4 is bringing alternate colorspaces at long last, but CSS4 is still in working draft stage,